# Is it possible to delete all the resources created by AWS CDK bootstrapping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I was playing with AWS CDK and now I want to clean it all.

Is it possible to delete all the resources (bucket, roles, whatever...) created by `cdk bootstrap` using a CDK command?

Should I do it manually? In this case, is there a way to know what exact resources CDK bootstrapping process did create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrapping just deploys a Cloudformation stack - deleting the resources requires you to delete this stack. It's called `CDKToolkit` by default.

You will need to manually remove the S3 Asset bucket after emptying it, though.

The feature request to add a CDK CLI command for destroying the bootstrap stack is being tracked here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/986

Comment: Thank you! +1 for the feature-request link